# Convert between two currencies by the click of a button in the same cells

Tags: vba, excel, currency

I want to create a function in my Excel workbook that converts all the cells in the three sheets I am currently using with a currency format from one currency (SLL) to another (DKK) by the click of a button (the same button converts in SLL or in DKK depending on which currency the values currently are in).

My code is:

```
Sub convertcurrency()

    Dim userrate1 As Long
    Dim userrate2 As Long

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        userrate1 = 625

        If Cells.NumberFormat = "DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "SLL" & userrate1 * cell.Value

        ElseIf Cells.NumberFormat = "SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "DKK" & (1 / userrate1) * cell.Value _

    End If

End Sub
```

But it's not working. The error is "Compile error. Else without if". But how can I use else without if, if I need to include the second restriction.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim userrate1 As Long
Dim userrate2 As Long

For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    userrate1 = 625

    If Cells.NumberFormat = "DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" _
    Then cell.Value = userrate1 * cell.Value

        If Cells.NumberFormat = "SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = (1 / userrate1) * cell.Value _



End Sub
```

try this

Comment: If then statement used here is a single standalone statement.  Anything written after then the scope of the if statement gets limited to that line only.

Comment: Hi Sandesh. I've modified the code to: Sub convertcurrency()

    Dim userrate1 As Long
    Dim userrate2 As Long
    
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        userrate1 = 625
                
        If Cells.NumberFormat = "DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "SLL" & userrate1 * cell.Value
        
        If Cells.NumberFormat = "SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "DKK" & (1 / userrate1) * cell.Value

    Next

End Sub. No error codes, but it is not working.

Comment: Is the currecny SLL or DKK part of the cell value?

Comment: What is the default.  The number format shared by you does not exit in Excel.

Comment: The default is DKK, but does it matter? Currently all the "currency-formated" cells are set to SLL. Just recorded a macro to see what happens when convert from SLL to DKK and the output is:     Range("G15").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$DKK] #,##0". I've tried to implement this in my code, but it isn't working.

Comment: Sub convertcurrency()

    Dim userrate1 As Long
    Dim userrate2 As Long
    
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        userrate1 = 625
                
        If Cells.NumberFormat = "[$DKK] #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "SLL " & userrate1 * cell.Value
        
        If Cells.NumberFormat = "[$SLL] #,##0.00" _
        Then cell.Value = "DKK " & (1 / userrate1) * cell.Value

    Next

End Sub

Comment: Try these number formats... [$DKK] #,##0.00 and [$SLL] #,##0.00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83187/discussion-between-sandesh-jadhav-m-and-saud).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the functionality but this corrects the syntax.

```
Sub convertCurrency()

    Dim userrate1 As Double, userrate2 As Double
    Dim cr As Range, currRng As Range, ws As Worksheet

    userrate1 = 625
    userrate2 = 1 / userrate1

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            On Error Resume Next
            Set currRng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not currRng Is Nothing Then
                For Each cr In currRng
                    If cr.NumberFormat = "DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" Then
                        cr.Value = "SLL" & userrate1 * cr.Value           '<-one of these should probably be userrate2
                    ElseIf cr.NumberFormat = "SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" Then
                        cr.Value = "DKK" & (1 / userrate1) * cr.Value     '<-one of these should probably be userrate2
                    Else
                        'send non-matching number format to the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) to see what was missed
                        debug.print cr.numberformat
                    End If
                Next cr
            End If

            On Error Resume Next
            Set currRng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not currRng Is Nothing Then
                For Each cr In currRng
                    If cr.NumberFormat = "DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" Then
                        cr.Value = "SLL" & userrate1 * cr.Value           '<-one of these should probably be userrate2
                    ElseIf cr.NumberFormat = "SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" Then
                        cr.Value = "DKK" & (1 / userrate1) * cr.Value     '<-one of these should probably be userrate2
                    Else
                        'send non-matching number format to the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) to see what was missed
                        debug.print cr.numberformat
                    End If
                Next cr
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I've attempted to correct your logic the best that I could from your description in the original question and the comments. The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) will only look at numbers that are not produces by formulas which is what your original code indicated.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. The button inside every sheet (which is the same across all the sheets) should convert all the "currency-formated" values in each cell from SLL to DKK (if the current values are in SLL) and from DKK to SLL (if the current values are in DKK). Why doens't "For each cell (...)" make sense? Cells are in different formats, not only in currency format.

Comment: a) you never declared `cell` so it was an object b) for each Cell in [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) means that Cell was a worksheet, not a cell or [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) no matter what you named it d) you never closed the [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)

Comment: Sry, I forgot to mention that some of the "currency formated" values do have contain formulas, while others do not. Regarding "userrate2", can't I just use the reciprocal value of the first one, if I am only converting between to currencies or do I explicitly have to define them?

Comment: OK, I added a second iteration for numbers produced by formulas

Comment: I've tried the second iteration. It came up with an error. Then I made these changes:

"DKK" & "$ #,##0.00" => "[$DKK] #,##0"
                       
"SLL" & "$ #,##0.00" = "[$SLL] #,##0" 

and 4 values were succesfully converted, but the remaining 200-300 didn't convert. And when I clicked on the button again it didn't change back to the original currency.

Comment: It would appear that the number formats are not what you believe them to be. Take a look at the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) for the non-matching output that my routine sent there. Edit your original question to include samples of the number format strings.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by samples of the number format strings. Is it possible to somehow upload the excel file? The values seem to be in the right format.